# Define a read-only property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, xcode8

How do you define a read-only property in Swift? I have one parent class which needs to define a public property eg. `itemCount`. Here's my code:

```
Class Parent: UIView {
  private(set) var itemCount: Int = 0
}

class Child {
  private(set) override var itemCount {
    get {
      return items.count
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error: `Cannot override mutable property with read-only property`

---

#### Option 1 - Protocols:

Well I can't use a protocol because they can't inherit from classes (`UIView`)

#### Option 2 - Composition:

I add a `var view = UIView` to my Child class and drop the `UIView` inheritance from my `Parent` class. This seems to be the only possible way, but in my actual project it seems like the wrong thing to do, eg. `addSubview(myCustomView.view)`

#### Option 3 - Subclass `UIView` on the `Child` class

I can't do this either because I intend to have multiple related `Child` classes with different properties and behaviour, and I need to be able to declare instances of my `Child` classes as the `Parent` class to take advantage of `UIView`'s properties and `Parent`'s public properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `Computed Property` which (like a method) can be overridden.

```
class Parent: UIView {
    var itemCount: Int { return 0 }
}

class Child: Parent {
    override var itemCount: Int { return 1 }
}
```

### Update (as reply to the comment below)

This is how you declared and override a function

```
class Parent: UIView {
    func doSomething() { print("Hello") }
}

class Child: Parent {
    override func doSomething() { print("Hello world!") }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would I have to use `var` and `override var` to declare functions as well?

Comment: No, to [declare a function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158) you use the `func` keyword.

Comment: I haven't been able to define it in `Parent` and been able to successfully override it in a `Child` class

Answer (score 4):

You can declare setter as private while getter is public.

```
public class someClass {
    public private(set) var count: String
}
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVcPrWhizqY)

Comment: The link is dead. :(

Answer (score 1):

As one more option you can use private variable for read/write and another for read-only. Count you're using for internal class changes, and numberOfItems for public access. Little bit weird, but it solves the problem.

```
class someClass {
    private var count: Int = 0
    var numberOfItems: Int { return count }

    func doSomething()  {
       count += 1
    }
}
```